# Sort in an array

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

I have an issue with my method when I try to sort :

Here's what my code look like :

```
public void sort() 
{
  boolean found=true;
  int i = 0;
  String temp;
  while(found)
  {
    found = false;

    for ( i = 0; i<cars.length-1; i++)
    {
      if (cars[i].compareToIgnoreCase(cars[i+1])> 0)
      {
```

I got this far but still not sure on how to sort them ?

Comment: any reason why you don't use the sort() function?

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
Arrays.sort(cars);
```

if cars are non-standard type then write your own `Comparator` (lets name it `comp`) and do:

```
Arrays.sort(cars, comp);
```

[Here's](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) documentation of `Comparator` interface.

**Update**
Or, just implement `Comparable` interface to class of cars, as  Mr. Polywhirl said below.

Answer (score 2):

You already initialized temp, just move cars[i] to temp and then cars[i+1] to cars[i] then temp to cars[i+1], then found =true to leave loop translate this to code

Answer (score 1):

How about using a built-in method? [`Arrays.sort()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#sort%28java.lang.Object%5b%5d%29) will work just fine.

Answer (score 1):

What way do you want this data sorted? Also I am assuming you want to do this manually? If not, then use Java's built in Arrays.sort() method as mentioned above.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a complete implementation of the [bubble sort algorithm in Java from Rosetta Code](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithms/Bubble_sort#Java):

```
public static <E extends Comparable<? super E>> void bubbleSort(E[] comparable) {
    boolean changed = false;
    do {
        changed = false;
        for (int a = 0; a < comparable.length - 1; a++) {
            if (comparable[a].compareTo(comparable[a + 1]) > 0) {
                E tmp = comparable[a];
                comparable[a] = comparable[a + 1];
                comparable[a + 1] = tmp;
                changed = true;
            }
        }
    } while (changed);
}
```

Since you're probably doing this for a class, you should try to understand what is happening. Use lots of `System.out.println()` statements to show how your program ran.

You should also find out how to use the debugger on your IDE. It will allow you to see how the program runs line by line, and how the data changes.